# Tag Wiki and Access to Moderator Tools

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This is a bit odd... Since hitting the 10K rep, I've tried to help out the mods with edit approvals and the like and that appears to include tag wiki edits. The odd thing is, I don't have normal editing capability for tag wiki. This strikes me as an odd hole in the process... I can approve edits but can't make them? Any ideas?

Comment: This is no answer, but "Edit all tag wikis" is part of the 20k "Trusted User" privs. http://photo.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user

Comment: @mattdm - Yeah, which is what confused the heck out of me... At half the needed rep, I can approve edits, but not make them? Seems pretty odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this is by-design.

At 10k we ensure at least 2 people look at the tag wiki edit (the editor and suggester)
At 20k we allow you to edit whatever you want

---

The idea is that we want more people looking at the wikis cause they are so prominent on the site.

Besides, we need to be able to give you something at 20k :)

Comment: Ah, I get it, that makes some sense. It's still a bit weird, but I can see the concept. Thanks.

Comment: I also discovered there's a limit on the approvals... One of our lads was busy today with good edits and I suddenly could no longer approve them having reached a cap for one user. So, now it makes a lot more sense.